# Python, Pyglet draw shape pixels inside stencil mask

Tags: stencil-buffer

I'm facing this trouble that I tried to solve in so many ways that I found on the internet, but everything I tried didn't any visual difference. I want to draw a shape discarding all pixels that are outside of the circle mask, in the example code bellow I'm using a rectangle mask instead of a circle, just for show what I'm trying to do. And the only thing I can do is a hole in the blue shape. I want to cut everything outside the mask, like a scissor, but I wanna use a circle mask, and smooth. Could you guys help me? What code lines is missing?

```
import pyglet
from pyglet.gl import gl
from pyglet.gl import*
from pyglet.window import Window

Config = pyglet.gl.Config(sample_buffers=1, samples=16, double_buffer=True)
window = Window(800, 640, caption='Stencil Test Draw with mask', config=Config)
print([i for i in dir(gl) if 'invert'.lower() in i.lower()])

@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    """ alpha blending """
    gl.glEnable(gl.GL_BLEND)
    gl.glBlendFunc(gl.GL_SRC_ALPHA, gl.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)

    """ Trying to smooth stencil Circle Mask """
    glEnable(GL_SMOOTH)

    """ Draw a background """
    glColor4f(1, 1, 0, 1.0)
    pyglet.graphics.draw(4, GL_QUADS, ('v2f', [0,0, 0,500, 500,500, 500,0]))

    glEnable(GL_STENCIL_TEST)
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
    glColorMask(False, False, False, False)

    """ Draw Stencil Mask (I'm trying with a circle shape, but in this example I use rect) """
    pyglet.graphics.draw(4, GL_QUADS, ('v2f', [250,250, 250,300, 300,300, 300,250]))

    glColorMask(True, True, True, True)

    """ Draw rectangle pixels only inside stencil mask """
    glColor4f(0, 0, 1, 1.0)
    pyglet.graphics.draw(4, GL_QUADS, ('v2f', [200,200, 200,350, 350,350, 350,200]))

    """ Remove stencil test """
    glDisable(GL_STENCIL_TEST)

pyglet.app.run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem:

```
import pyglet
from pyglet.gl import gl
from pyglet.gl import*
from pyglet.window import Window

Config = pyglet.gl.Config(sample_buffers=1, samples=16, double_buffer=True, stencil_size=8)
window = Window(800, 640, caption='Stencil Test Draw with mask', config=Config)

@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    """ alpha blending """
    gl.glEnable(gl.GL_BLEND)
    gl.glBlendFunc(gl.GL_SRC_ALPHA, gl.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)

    """ Trying to smooth stencil Circle Mask """
    glEnable(GL_SMOOTH)

    """Clear """
    glClearStencil(0)
    glEnable(GL_STENCIL_TEST)
    glColorMask(GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE)
    glStencilFunc(GL_NEVER, 0, 1)
    glStencilOp(GL_INVERT, GL_INVERT, GL_INVERT)

    """ Draw Stencil Mask (I'm trying with a circle shape, but in this example I use rect) """
    glColor4f(1, 0, 0, 1.0)
    pyglet.graphics.draw(4, GL_QUADS, ('v2f', [250,250, 250,300, 300,300, 300,250]))

    """ Now, we want only the framebuffer to be updated if stencil value is 1 """
    """ Draw rectangle pixels only inside stencil mask """
    glColorMask(GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE)
    glStencilFunc(GL_EQUAL, 1, 1)
    glStencilOp(GL_ZERO, GL_ZERO, GL_ZERO)
    glColor4f(0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
    pyglet.graphics.draw(4, GL_QUADS, ('v2f', [200,200, 200,350, 350,350, 350,200]))

    """ Remove stencil test """
    glDisable(GL_STENCIL_TEST)

pyglet.app.run()
```